# ¿CÓMO CANCELAR UNA FUNCION SETTIMEOUT?

Tags: php, javascript, function, timeout

Estoy ejecutando un script por medio de un echo, el cual corre una función setTimeout, (que redirecciona a la home en 7 seg.) y también estoy arrojando una alerta. Si el usuario oprime un botón de ésta alerta, necesito que se aborte esa función setTimeOut y que ya no redireccione a ningún lado. si no oprime nada durante los 7 segúndos que ésta aparece, que lo redireccione.

```
echo "<script>

porfa(true); //Aquí le mando true a la función "porfa()"
               para que empiece a contar el setTimeout y redireccione

//Aquí empieza la alerta, la cuál tiene el botón para que el usuario aborte el redireccionamiento
$.confirm({
    title: '¡Oops!',
    content: 'Ésta ventana se cerrará automáticamente.',
    buttons: {
               tryAgain: {
               text: 'Intentar de nuevo',
               action: function(){
                        $('#modalRegistro').modal('show'); 
                        porfa(false);
                        }
                },
                close: function (){
                    window.location.href = '".$url."';
                }
            }
        });

   //Aquí está la función donde intento "abortar" el setTimeOut, si el usuario oprime
    "intentar de nuevo"

function porfa(valor){

    if(valor){
         return setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = '".$url."'; }, 7000);
    }else{
         return false;
    }
}
</script>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes del `porfa(true);` crea una variable vacía; `let recarga`. Luego en la función `porfa()`, en vez de retornar el `setTimeout` asignaselo a la variable que has declarado antes:

`if(valor){
         recarga = setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = '".$url."'; }, 7000);
         return recarga;
    }else{
         return false;
    }`

Y ahora para cancelar esta función basta con que hagas:

```
clearTimeout(recarga);
```

Un saludo!